# Creating .APK file from html file

Tags: apk

I would like some script or a dll that would all me from my software that I have written to create a .apk file.

So basically my software creates a website. In my program,I want to make a call to a dll or some script so convert that site to apk. I would need to pass paramaters to it

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

I think that you should take a look at [Phonegap's website](http://phonegap.com) and setup android development environment to create android app apk files. 
Phonegap helps you in easily creating android applications in html. Over there you can use iframes to convert a website into a phonegap based android application.